# unable to change the BooleanField value in Django

Tags: python, django, radio-button

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # on_deleting user, profile will also be deleted
    image = models.ImageField(default="profilepic.jpg",upload_to="profile_pictures")
    dob = models.DateField(null=True)
    bio = models.TextField(null=True)
    anonymous = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def profile_edit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'your account has been updated')
            return redirect('users:profile')
    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileForm()
    context = {
        'u_form' : u_form,
        'p_form' : p_form
    }
    return render(request, 'users/profile_edit.html',context)
```

**in users/profile_edit.html**

```
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="anonymous"  value='True'>Anonymous</label>
          <label class="ml-5 radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="anonymous" value='False' checked>Non-Anonymous</label>
        </div>
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile

class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name','last_name']


class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image','dob','bio']
```

the rest of the form works fine (updates the contents of profile as expected) but the BooleanField for anonymous does not work when the radio buttons are clicked before submitting the form

Comment: can you post `ProfileForm` too

Comment: thank you @harshil9968, i realized my mistake after your comment

Answer (score 0):

after @harshil9968 asked for profile form, I realized that i had not included anonymous in my profileform, hence the output of radio button was not being processed on form submit